# Loop through a table and pass if that row has the right text

Tags: ruby, rspec

On the web page you can filter what applications are displayed based on the status (Active, Inactive, or Deleted).

When the "Show All" is selected, then applications with a status of Active, Inactive, or Deleted should be displayed.

I've got it to loop through the text of the cells using this code:

```
     $ie.table.each do | row | 
          row.each do | cell | 
            puts cell.text() 
             # Passes if the text is either Active, Inactive or Deleted.
           end 
         end
```

If the text for the the rows it loops through is either Active, Inactive, or Deleted the test should pass.

Comment: What kind of object is $ie? Seems like you're using more than rspec--is it Watir? Also, you haven't mentioned how you want to handle multiple cells if they're different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't clear by your example what is the cells and where the information is for the status. Since that is the case I will assume you can access the status in **row[0]** and the filter text is in a var called **filter** and you intend to skip displaying the whole row.

So with that assumption, in my head your data looks like:

```
Status   | Name
--------------------
Active   | Foo App
Inactive | Bar App
Active   | Baz App
Deleted  | Blam App
```

And if that be the case:

```
$ie.table.each do | row |
  if filter == 'All'
    next unless %w(Active Inactive Deleted).include?(row[0])
  else
    next unless row[0] == filter
  end

  row.each do | cell | 
    puts cell.text()
  end 
end
```

And if the assumption is made that there can be no status other than (Active Inactive Deleted) then we can simplify it:

```
$ie.table.each do | row |
  unless filter == 'All'
    next unless row[0] == filter
  end

  row.each do | cell | 
    puts cell.text()
  end 
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You question would benefit from having an example. But I am guessing you are looking for something like:

```
puts cell.text() if ["Active", "Inactive", "Deleted"].include? cell.text()
```